# Divide generic.xaml to several files

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I got generic.xaml file in Windows Phone project, and it is getting too big. How to divide generic.xaml to several files?

I know about `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` but, I can not make it work. Project compiles, but then I got runtime exception when Page is trying to parse xaml resource.

I tryed:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="WatermarkedPinBox.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Help me please, I do not like big resource files. It is hard to keep their structure in good state.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not want to do it again to get error message, but it was like: "XAML parse error at line...", at line where I tryed to use styles from WatermarkedPinBox.xaml, parser could not load it

Answer (score -1):

You can use `MergedDictionaries` to split your `Generic.xaml` file. Take a look on this example:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mscorlib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourProjectName;component/Themes/YourSecondResourceFileName.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourProjectName;component/Themes/YourThirdResourceFileName.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

`Build Action` for YourSecondResourceFileName.xaml and YourThirdResourceFileName.xaml must set to `Page`.

Comment: it yields same runtime exception actually